# Center Image CRUD gallery with Bootstrap

Tags: css, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

Hi so I'm working on a site with an image gallery and I decided to use a Codeigniter and a library called Image CRUD for some of the backend stuff, and Twitter Bootstrap for the front end. Its pretty basic stuff. The problem is Image CRUD generates a lot of its own code  for the front end so I'm having trouble getting it to look the way I want. Im trying to make a responsive gallery that resizes and stays centered on a bunch of different devices. This should be a piece of cake with bootstrap, but for some reason it just won't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Heres the code for the images that Image CRUD outputs:

```
<ul class='photos-crud'>
            <li id="photos_206">
            <div class='photo-box'>
                <a href='link_to.jpg' title="" target='_blank' class="color-box" rel="color-box" tabindex="-1"><img src='link_to_thumb__b551b-6.jpg' width='290' height='260' class="img-responsive basic-image" /></a>
                                                                            <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
            <li id="photos_203">
            <div class='photo-box'>
                <a href='link_to.jpg' title="" target='_blank' class="color-box" rel="color-box" tabindex="-1"><img src='link_to_thumb.jpg' width='290' height='260' class="img-responsive basic-image" /></a>
                                                                            <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
            <li id="photos_204">
            <div class='photo-box'>
                <a href='link_to.jpg' title="" target='_blank' class="color-box" rel="color-box" tabindex="-1"><img src='link_to_thumb.jpg' width='290' height='260' class="img-responsive basic-image" /></a>
                                                                            <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
            <li id="photos_205">
            <div class='photo-box'>
                <a href='link_to.jpg' title="" target='_blank' class="color-box" rel="color-box" tabindex="-1"><img src='link_to_thumb.jpg' width='290' height='260' class="img-responsive basic-image" /></a>
                                                                            <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
            <li id="photos_202">
            <div class='photo-box'>
                <a href='link_to.jpg' title="" target='_blank' class="color-box" rel="color-box" tabindex="-1"><img src='link_to_thumb.jpg' width='290' height='260' class="img-responsive basic-image" /></a>
                                                                            <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
            <li id="photos_201">
            <div class='photo-box'>
                <a href='link_to.jpg' title="" target='_blank' class="color-box" rel="color-box" tabindex="-1"><img src='link_to_thumb.jpg' width='290' height='260' class="img-responsive basic-image" /></a>
                                                                            <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue may be with your image width/height having exact dimensions. If you can get rid of that and let bootstrap take over, that'd be great. Responsive images are usually 100% of the parent width and that parent having a percentage of something else. Maybe you can use SASS to @extend bootstrap styles into the generated elements so..

```
.photos-crud { @extend .row }
.photos-crud > li { @extend .col-md-3}
```

Something like that will setup the grid for laying out the images, then if you can remove the auto-generated dimensions, great, but if not maybe use !important to override the dimensions like..

```
.photos-crud > li img {width:100% !important; height:auto !important;}
```